# Product Prices are mismatch in invoice and invoice PDF magento 2.2.1

Tags: magento2.2, magento-2.2.1

I am getting different price in invoice and invoice PDf for the bundle product. Actually, The prices in the invoice pdf are wrong. I am getting right price in order, order email, invoice, invoice email or everywhere in the application, but invoice PDf price is wrong only Bundle product. 
Please see the attach screen shot.

**Invoice:**
[image]

Invoice Pdf:
[image]

Please suggest, who can I solve this?

Comment: Any third party extesnion used for PDF design  or somethings?

Comment: No, I am not using any third party module.

Answer (score 0):

This is core Magento issue, so don't  waste time.
Get more details : https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12856

This issue occurred after upgrading Magento from 2.1.8 to Magento 2.2.1  with only bundle product. Just track this issue on github to get the solution.